# Storing and accessing private data

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-cloud-storage

My goal is to offer a service for user of my website to store their private notes.
I want that users can trust the service, therefore the data should not be accessible for my company.

Can i realize this with google-cloud-storage and oauth-2.0 authentication? I would use the Google Cloud Storage JSON API to send the notes directly from the browser into the cloud.

What would be the basic steps to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to handle this, depending on how you want to handle authentication. If you want to make sure that your application cannot access the objects and only the users can, you'll need the users to have Google accounts and authenticate your app to act as their agent using OAuth 2.

Your app could involve a piece of JavaScript that would prompt the user to authenticate with Google and grant it access to Google Cloud Storage under their name. It would then receive a token that it could use to act as them. From there, it would upload the note using that token with an ACL granting permissions only to the uploader.

The uploaded object would go into your bucket, but it would be owned by the end user. You'd have the ability to delete it, but not to read it, and your bucket would be billed for storage and access.

The downside here is that all of your users would need to have Google accounts that they could entrust to your application for short periods of time.

Here are some details on the OAuth 2 exchange: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent

Here's the JavaScript client that does a lot of the authorization heavy lifting for you:
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/

And an example of using that library for authorization:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples#AuthorizingandMakingAuthorizedRequests

Another alternative would be for the user to upload directly to the cloud using YOUR credentials via signed URLs, but if you went down this road, you would be able to read the notes after they were uploaded.

Comment: I am using the following client: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-getting-started-javascript/blob/master/index.html.
I am able to insert an object , but the project owner can read it. So i am trying to set 'x-goog-acl': 'private' in the gapi.client.request headers section but have no luck. I have also tried other places but the project owner can always read it.

Comment: Ahh. That is the Javascript client for the JSON API, the documentation for which is here: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert

This API does not use the x-goog-acl header. Instead, ACLs are set via an ACL property of the uploaded object. The request body should be a JSON object containing an "acl" property that contains a list of controls, like this: {"acl":[{"entity":"user-MyEmailAddressOrIdNumber", "role":"OWNER"}]}.

Comment: Or you can just use encryption. Users encrypt the data and store it encrypted. The user should own the key and the key should never leave the client. That way you have the data but it's useless to you.